# Prevent re-rendering unchanged items in todo app with React Context and useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a simple React todo app using context and useReducer, and I'm unsure how to prevent every single todo item from re-rendering when one of the changes. When one todo changes, an action is dispatched, causing the state to update. Specifically, the reducer returns a new copy of the state in which one todo is updated and the other todos are the same.

Given that state changes, it makes sense that all of the todos re-render when one is updated. However, my todos component passes the necessary props to each todo -- and those props don't change -- so I'd think that the `todo` components that don't have to change props wouldn't re-render. Instead, when I use dev tools and check the box to highlight re-renders, I see that they all-flash. What am I missing?

```
// from the reducer
    case "EDIT_TODO":
      return state.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === action.payload.id) {
          return {
            ...todo,
            desc: action.payload.value
          };
        } else {
          return todo;
        }
      });
    default:
      return state;
```

```
// from the todos component
<ul className="TodosApp">
    {todos.map(todo => (
        <li key={todo.id}>
            <Todo
              id={todo.id}
              complete={todo.complete}
              description={todo.desc}
            />
       </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

```
// from the todo component
// handleToggleTodo function dispatches an "EDIT_TODO" action
const EditTodo = ({ id, description, complete }) => {
    // not showing the handleToggleTodo function, which dispatches an "EDIT_TODO" action
    // and has a payload with the todo id and the updated todo description.
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={complete} onChange={handleToggleTodo} />
        <input
           className="Todo-input"
           type="text"
           value={description}
           onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </Fragment>
   )
```

My work is in codesandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-fire-8hirp?fontsize=14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use React `memo()` method.

https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/

You need to wrap you stateless component with react memo and component will not be re-rendered if props are the same.

```
import React from "react";
import { useTodosState } from "./todos_context";
import Todo from "./todo";

const Todos = () => {
  const todos = useTodosState();
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Todos</h2>
      <ul className="TodosApp">
        {todos.map(todo => (
          <li key={todo.id}>
            <Todo
              id={todo.id}
              complete={todo.complete}
              description={todo.desc}
            />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

const MemoizeTodos = React.memo(Todos);

export default MemoizeTodos;
```

> When deciding to update DOM, React first renders your component, then
>   compares the result with the previous render result. If the render
>   results are different, React updates the DOM.
>
> Current vs previous render results comparison is fast. But you can
>   speed up the process under some circumstances.
>
> When a component is wrapped in `React.memo()`, React renders the
>   component and memoizes the result. Before the next render, if the new
>   props are the same, React reuses the memoized result skipping the next
>   rendering.

Comment: Actually, perhaps I misunderstand your response. When I try that, I still see every todo re-rendering. You can see it in the codesandbox link above

Comment: You can use console.log to track render. As I see only new todo property are rendered.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I achieve the result I'd expect when I memoize the individual `Todo` component rather than `Todos`.

Comment: I am glad to hear that :)